# How to add an option to HTML select using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html select like:

```
<select id="airports-sel">
      <option data-group="1" value="1">Madrid–Barajas</option>
      <option data-group="1" value="2">Torrejón de Ardoz Airport</option>
      <option data-group="2" value="3">Milan-Malpensa</option>
      <option data-group="2" value="4">Milan-Linate</option>
</select>
```

I need to add a new airport to this select using jQuery, I try to use the following code but it's not working:

```
$('#airports-sel').append($('<option>', {
      value: 5,
      text: Paris-Orly Airport,
      data-group: 3
}));
```

This works without "data-group" but it's very important to me to have the data-group set on every option, can you please provide an example of how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has a couple of problems:

1. You don't use strings correctly; strings must be enclosed in quotes.
2. You use a hyphen-separated key in your object which must also be enclosed in quotes, or you'll get a syntax error.

**Code:**

```
$('#airports-sel').append($('<option>', {
      value: 5,
      text: "Paris-Orly Airport",
      "data-group": 3
}));
```

Comment: Why down voted this answer? This is correct one and it's not a duplicate as mentioned in comment.

Comment: @Alex, if it solves your problem then you should accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps!

```
     $("#airports-sel").append("<option data-group=3 value='>Paris-Orly Airport</option>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add option by simply writing following code in jquery.

```
$("#airports-sel").append("<option data-group='3' value='5'>Paris-Orly Airport</option>");
```